# ¿Cómo obtener longitud de cada elemento de una lista?

Tags: python

Mi objetivo es obtener en la lista `longitudes = []` la cantidad de caracteres que posee cada índice de la lista de listas `lista[1][i]`

```
lista =[ ['letras =a', ' b ', 'c', ' d', 'e', 'f deletrear\n'], ['letras2 =d', ' f ', 'd', ' e', 'h', 'f deletrear\n']]
longitud = len(lista[1]) 

longitudes = []
for i in range(0, longitud):
    longitudes = len(lista[1][i]) # o debería poner longitudes[i] ?
print(longitudes)
```

Esto solo me imprime un 12, cuando a mi me gustaría
que imprimiera las longitudes tipo `[4, 3, 4]` y así sucesivamente. (Esos valores de longitud los inventé)

Espero y alguien me pudiera ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las listas son iterables, por ende las puedes poner directamente en un ciclo.

No entendí bien si quieres una sublista de longitudes por cada sublista del arreglo principal. De ser así, entonces el código sería:

```
longitudes = []
for sublista in lista:
    long_sublist = []
    for elemento in sublista:
        long_sublist.append(len(elemento))
    longitudes.append(long_sublist)

print(longitudes)
# imprime: [[9, 3, 1, 2, 1, 12], [10, 3, 1, 2, 1, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, usaremos el método `len()` para obtener la longitud de la lista, así nos ahorramos tener que definir una variable adicional, luego haremos un `for` y un `append` por cada elemento de la lista y obtendremos la longitud con `len()`

```
lista =[ ['letras =a', ' b ', 'c', ' d', 'e', 'f deletrear\n'], ['letras2 =d', ' f ', 'd', ' e', 'h', 'f deletrear\n']]

longitudes = []

for i in range(0, (len(lista[1]))):
    longitudes.append(len(lista[1][i]))

print(longitudes)
```

Resultado:

```
[10, 3, 1, 2, 1, 12]
```